# Python 3.7 os.system strange output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code for simple turn on / turn off internet connection

```
import os
while True:
    ans = input('Enter en or dis: ')
    if ans.lower() == 'dis':
        os.system('ipconfig /release')
        print('in disabled')
    elif ans.lower() == 'en':
        os.system('ipconfig /renew')
        print('in en')
```

And strange output

When disabling

```
Enter en or dis: dis

����ன�� ��⮪��� IP ��� Windows

���������� �믮����� ����樨 ��� ���஢����� ���, ���� �⪫�祭� ���.
���������� �믮����� ����樨 ��� ������祭�� �� �����쭮� ��* 9, ���� �⪫�祭� ���.
���������� �믮����� ����樨 ��� ������祭�� �� �����쭮� ��* 10, ���� �⪫�祭� ���.

������ Ethernet Ethernet:

   DNS-���䨪� ������祭�� . . . . . : 
   ������� IPv6-���� ������ . . . : Deleted_by_me_ipv6
   �᭮���� ��. . . . . . . . . : 

������ ���஢����� �����쭮� �� ���஢����� ���:

   ����ﭨ� �।�. . . . . . . . : �।� ��।�� ������㯭�.
   DNS-���䨪� ������祭�� . . . . . : 

������ ���஢����� �����쭮� �� ������祭�� �� �����쭮� ��* 9:

   ����ﭨ� �।�. . . . . . . . : �।� ��।�� ������㯭�.
   DNS-���䨪� ������祭�� . . . . . : 

������ ���஢����� �����쭮� �� ������祭�� �� �����쭮� ��* 10:

   ����ﭨ� �।�. . . . . . . . : �।� ��।�� ������㯭�.
   DNS-���䨪� ������祭�� . . . . . : 
in disabled
```

And when enabling

```
Enter en or dis: en

����ன�� ��⮪��� IP ��� Windows

���������� �믮����� ����樨 ��� ���஢����� ���, ���� �⪫�祭� ���.
���������� �믮����� ����樨 ��� ������祭�� �� �����쭮� ��* 9, ���� �⪫�祭� ���.
���������� �믮����� ����樨 ��� ������祭�� �� �����쭮� ��* 10, ���� �⪫�祭� ���.

������ Ethernet Ethernet:

   DNS-���䨪� ������祭�� . . . . . : 
   ������� IPv6-���� ������ . . . : Deleted_by_me_ipv6
   IPv4-����. . . . . . . . . . . . : Deleted_by_me_ipv4
   ��᪠ ����� . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   �᭮���� ��. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

������ ���஢����� �����쭮� �� ���஢����� ���:

   ����ﭨ� �।�. . . . . . . . : �।� ��।�� ������㯭�.
   DNS-���䨪� ������祭�� . . . . . : 

������ ���஢����� �����쭮� �� ������祭�� �� �����쭮� ��* 9:

   ����ﭨ� �।�. . . . . . . . : �।� ��।�� ������㯭�.
   DNS-���䨪� ������祭�� . . . . . : 

������ ���஢����� �����쭮� �� ������祭�� �� �����쭮� ��* 10:

   ����ﭨ� �।�. . . . . . . . : �।� ��।�� ������㯭�.
   DNS-���䨪� ������祭�� . . . . . : 
in en
```

I don't understand why output is so strange. When I do `ipconfig /renew` or `ipconfig /release` in command line output is OK, so I guess this is Unicode problem, but I can't find how to change `os.system` output Unicode to utf-8 or something like that.

Comment: How are you running your Python file?

Comment: PyCharm "Run" button

Comment: Try running it on the command line. There's something weird going on with PyCharm's internal representation mechanism.